# IF OBJECT_ID IS NOT NULL SQL Server

Tags: sql

tengo la siguiente duda

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.Scores

CREATE TABLE Scores (H int not null)
```

Es sobre la siguiente Query, entiendo que si existe la tabla (no es null) la borra y la vuelve a crear, lo que entiendo por el condicional if es que si no existiera no entraria al condicional (ya que al no existir seria null, y contradice la condicion) y por lo tanto no la borraria y volveria a crear. Pero hago pruebas y si no existe la tabla y ejecuto ese Query aun asi se crea la tabla, como es que se crea si no está correcta la condicion de que la tabla no sea null? si no existe supongo seria null y no se ejecutaria lo de abajo

Comment: El `CREATE TABLE`  está afuera del bloque `IF` por lo que siempre se ejecuta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asegurarte que las dos líneas de código solo se ejecutan cuando se cumpla la condición del `IF` deberías utilizar el bloque `BEGIN END` de la siguiente forma

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE dbo.Scores
  CREATE TABLE Scores (H int not null)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas, en tu código (esto me ha ayudado mucho en c# también), drop y create no están al mismo nivel, drop está más indentado, tiene una tabulación más. Eso es porque depende su ejecución del if, y drop no. Generalmente, los grupos de sentencias/... que se ejecutan en un mismo bloque tienen la misma tabulación.

La solución es lo que te han comentado:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE dbo.Scores
  CREATE TABLE Scores (H int not null)
END
```